# .net core mvc Scaffolding don't recognize my database context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identity

Trying to create a Identity login in .net core mvc, using DB First approach.

ran the code
"dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MvcCore_Entity;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -f -c EntityDBContext -o Data"
to generate my models+dbcontext BUT whhen trying to add New Scaffolded Item > Identity, it didn't recognize my dbcontext, only if I add a new dbcontext using this "+" button or using code first approach.

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Q5a.png)

Comment: Could you pls share the tutorial you followed to do to scaffold action?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.